# Why am I getting unexpected identfier for express in Nginx?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, vps

I'm trying to deploy my MERN stack in hostinger's VPS, I follow the tutorial of lamadev, but right now I can't run my API. It gives me an error regarding to `express`

this is what I received
[image]

This is what my package looks like.

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

It's my firstime using VPS for deploying a mern stack

This is my github repo. https://github.com/cruz-emman/tuamarketplace.git

Answer (score 0):

***Change this in index.js file:***

```
import express from "express"
```

to:

```
const express = require("express");
```